# Is there a DVD authoring program that will run successfully under Wine?

Tags: wine, 19.10, dvd

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 19.10, soon to move to Ubuntu Studio 20.04.  However, this is a general Ubuntu 19.10 question.  Has anyone had any success running a Windows DVD authoring program with Wine?  I checked the WineHQ website for DVD authoring programs and found that they were no longer available.  I've tested several programs on an Ubuntu Studio virtual machine and found that they generally do not run, with the exception of DVD Lab Pro which is very old and will not create DVDs with 1080i or 4K resolution.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a problem or lack of feature you need that are not found on Linux or cross platform programs.

Comment: If you need a Windows DVD program and wine does not work, the best choice is to dual boot with Windows.  You would need to copy videos from Ubuntu to Windows, since windows will not see Ubuntu.  Second choice would be a VM windows, but slightly harder to make DVD disks.

Comment: The only DVD authoring program the I've found to work under Ubuntu 19.10 and the beta version of Ubuntu 20.04 is DeVeDe, which produces a horrible looking menu in my opinion.  Neither DVDStyler (my personal favorite) nor Bombono (an acceptable second choice) work.  I would prefer not to dual boot with Windows; I have dual booted in the past and don't particularly care for it.  What I have done is to set up VMs with Ubuntu 18.04 and MX Linux, both of which run DVDStyler flawlessly.  I know Ubuntu 18.04 will be supported until 2023.  I'm just looking ahead, for a plan B.

Comment: There is another wine like program called crossover that is a pay for.  You would have to research it if they do DVD programs first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [OpenDVDProducer](https://opendvdproducer.jonata.org) (also available on [Ubuntu Store](https://snapcraft.io/opendvdproducer))? It does not generate HD DVDs, but have more options regarding DVD menu than DeVeDe.

Comment: Actually I have tried OpenDVDProducer.  It's not bad.  I'm just looking for something better.  DVDStyler is really good, but does not run under Ubuntu 19.10 or 20.04.  Right now I'm running an ubuntu 18.04 and an MX LInux virtual machine to use DVDStyler to create DVD's.  I'm looking so that I don't have to rely on virtual machines.  Thanks for the suggestion.